# cwd not respected when spawning Node child process

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to spawn a synchronous child process using Node v11.1.0 and set the current working directory as below. I'm using Windows 10.

```
const options = {
  cwd: 'D:\\somepath\\node_modules\\.install-npm-version-temp-U9EUNd',
  stdio: 'inherit'
};
const command = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'npm.cmd' : 'npm';
childProcess.spawnSync(command, ['install', 'chalk@2.4.1'], options);
```

The parent process current working directory is `'D:\\somepath'` in this example.

After the child process has finished executing, I expect chalk@2.4.1 to be installed to the `cwd` set above, but it is not. Instead, it is being installed in `'D:\\somepath\\node_modules'`, which leads me to believe the current working directory of the child process is really the parent's current working directory. Further evidence to suggest this is, `'D:\\somepath\\package.json'` is modified as a result of the child process running to contain dependency `chalk@2.4.1` (it was not there in prior).

Note, the `cwd` path above is valid on my machine. The NPM command executes and reports success.

Based on the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options), I believe I'm using the spawnSync API correctly, but I'm having no luck debugging this. Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer is correct, however, I wanted to add a comment on how to achieve what I set out to do for others in case it's helpful. In order to avoid NPM looking up parent directories, I simply added an empty `node_modules` folder to my target directory (`cwd` in the example above). After doing this, NPM identifies it as a "sensible root" (using their words) to install the package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `package.json` file in `D:\somepath` and not in your `cwd`.

From the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#more-information):

> When installing locally, npm first tries to find an appropriate prefix folder. This is so that npm install foo@1.2.3 will install to the sensible root of your package, even if you happen to have cded into some other folder.
>
> Starting at the $PWD, npm will walk up the folder tree checking for a folder that contains either a package.json file, or a node_modules folder. If such a thing is found, then that is treated as the effective "current directory" for the purpose of running npm commands. (This behavior is inspired by and similar to git's .git-folder seeking logic when running git commands in a working dir.)
>
> If no package root is found, then the current folder is used.